# import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader extra steps?

Tags: csv, import

I tried to type my own code. But when I’m typing

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;    
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
```

It always show an error in eclipse.

I downloaded the java project, and it works fine.

The source is here
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-load-csv-file-to-database/comment-page-1/#comment-41747

I'm wondering is there any extra steps that I need to do to make this work?

Comment: I haven't run it, but eclips shows a readline below the line and suggested me to delete them

Comment: Yes, but what is the error message?